# My bluetooth is not working on my Windows 8 laptop?

Tags: windows-8, bluetooth

I have a ASUS Zenbook ultrabook and for some reason I can't turn on the Bluetooth icon. I've tried but it doesn't work. I'm dependent because my keyboard is connected to the laptop through that way. 
Should I reinstall and/or download some drivers to make it work? Or what has happened?

It worked before but not anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Like Mountain Lion mentionned, you'll have to download your bluetooth driver. In general, Windows 8 does a good job in supporting hardware, but sometimes, you might encounter a device that requires more specific drivers, hence why it's not working out of the box on your Asus laptop.

Also, you should make sure that your wifi radio is turned **on**, since some wireless cards (like the Intel centrino 6230) has the bluetooth module integrated. In other words, if it's not turned on, your bluetooth radio will also be turned off, which could explain why it's not working and why the icon is not appearing on the taskbar.

Comment: It worked before, but is it dependent on something else maybe like java?

Comment: Most probably not. I don't think there is any kind of relation between your Bluetooth driver and java. What you could do is revert back to an older state where your Bluetooth driver worked and look at which application actually got removed / changed.

You could also open the device manager and see if it's reporting any kind of warning.

Answer (score 0):

Download new bluetooth driver for windows 8 from the ASUS official site and install the software or refer this [link](http://drivers.windows8downloads.com/win8-asus-zenbook-touch-ux31a-intel-bluetooth-driver-2-6-1209-0268-for-windows-8-x64-iwlgu/) for the driver download.

Note: While installing bluetooth driver turn on your bluetooth hardware..